# Connecting to Deno MongoDb in Docker throws uncaught promise (in wsl2)

Tags: mongodb, docker, wsl-2, deno

The project runs in [Deno](https://deno.land/).
I'm trying to connect the [MongoClient](https://deno.land/x/mongo@v0.23.0) in Deno to a MongoDb container running in Docker.
The docker container is running in wsl2 with the wsl ip 172.18.96.38 and exposing port 27017.

Connecting to it with the following code leads to an error:

```
import { MongoClient } from "https://deno.land/x/mongo@v0.23.0/mod.ts";

const uri = 'mongodb://admin:admin@172.18.96.38:27017'
this.mClient = new MongoClient();
await this.mClient.connect(uri);
```

```
error: Uncaught (in promise) Error: MongoError: "Connection failed: MongoError: {\"ok\":0,\"errmsg\":\"no such command: 'hello'\",\"code\":59,\"codeName\":\"CommandNotFound\"}"
      throw new MongoError(`Connection failed: ${e.message || e}`);
            ^
    at MongoClient.connect (https://deno.land/x/mongo@v0.23.0/src/client.ts:26:13)
    at async Function.initMongoClient (file:///home/robert/repos/myDenoWebsite/backend/src/utils/mongoClientWrapper.ts:54:9)
```

According to the errmsg the error is 'no such command: 'hello'.
What does this mean?

This is my docker-compose.yml for mongo btw:

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:4.4-bionic
    container_name: my-mongodb
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin
    volumes:
      - mongodb:/data/db
      - mongoconfig:/data/configdb

volumes:
  mongodb:
  mongoconfig:
```

Comment: try `const uri = 'mongodb://admin:admin@127.0.0.1:27017'`

Comment: using 127.0.0.1 as localhost is not working when trying to connect to a docker container running in wsl2

Comment: Start the container and WAIT for the server startup (you can check the docker console log), then from **windows** check if you can connect to the MongoDB using a UI client, and then check to reach the container from wsl2, always using the 127.0.0.1. and 17017 port.

Comment: Deno says "No file, network, or environment access, unless explicitly enabled." How did you explicitly enabled network access from Deno to Mongo? The "wsl ip 172.18.96.38" sounds a bit confusing. Can you rephrase/elaborate? Can you telnet exposed docker port from the the host system/wsl ?

Comment: @AlexBlex providing ```--unstable --allow-net --allow-env --allow-read --allow-write --allow-plugin``` makes the use of this plugin possible in Deno.
wsl ip is retrieved via ```ip addr show eth0 | grep 'inet\b' | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d/ -f1``` which works for me. Connecting with the uri above to mongodbcompass works

Comment: A fix for the github issue you raised https://github.com/denodrivers/deno_mongo/issues/200#issuecomment-846420784 was merged few hrs ago. Did it solve the problem for you?

Comment: Yes works fine now. Thanks for your afford! @AlexBlex

Answer (score 1):

I got a same error, so I found an alternative way

This is my solution

```
import { MongoClient } from "https://deno.land/x/mongo@v0.29.2/mod.ts";

const conn = async () => {
  const client = new MongoClient();
  const srv = `mongodb+srv://admin:admin@172.18.96.38:27017/<Your Database>?authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1&retryWrites=true&w=majority`
  await client.connect(srv);
  return client;
}

export const getData = async () => {
  const conn = await conn()
  <Your Logic Here>
}
```